# Folders aren't shown in xcode

Tags: xcode

Why do some folders not appear in Xcode after I pull from github branch, even though they exist physically in the directory? It seems like Xcode hasn't updated its structure, and some files I've deleted and moved are showing as missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know about xcode but the same problem I have faced in vs code
editor . You can try solving this issue by using following steps.

Steps 1: click on view option in vs code.
Step 2: go to the option appearance  and then  click on the option primary side bar.
Now it will show your file and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode maintains its on view of the hierarchy. By default, it follows the tree structure on disk, but it can vary.

For example, you can delete a file from the view in Xcode, without trashing the local file.